# Outlook Mobile Service Enterprise Implementation

Tags: mobile, outlook, sms

I'm tasked with implementation of a custom OMS implementation that will stand between our users' Outlook clients and our SMS carrier. The standard OMS user setup prompts for URL, username and password, but we want to use Active Directory for authentication to OMS and for the configuration to be invisible to the users. That is, we don't want our users to ever see the signup prompt, yet of course the client needs to be authenticated when calling our OMS service (WCF/IIS 7.5). Additionally, when the user's password expires every X number of days, the user shouldn't have to reset their OMS service password. Ideally Outlook would pass a Kerberos ticket or something like that. Is that possible? Or am I stuck forcing a way for username/password to be sent to my OMS service?

Does anyone have experience with a similar enterprise OMS rollout?

Stan

Answer (score 0):

I develop such service and I successfully tested NTLM authentication.

All you need is such strings in web.config for your asmx.service:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

and MS Outlook will use authentication.
Ask questions if you have any.

BTW, do you have any problems in production or not?